# Return the highest value in the IEnumerable<T> list collection each step using OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

This is my first time asking a question on the site so I might not be doing this right. I need to find and return the highest values within my IEnumerable list but cannot show any duplicates. I also cannot use any copies or temporary collections, or use distinct. It must be done by first by taking the list and doing OrderByDescending.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T> (IEnumerable<T> sourcelist) where T : IComparable
{
    IEnumerable<T> list = sourcelist.OrderByDescending(item => item);

    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This is the result I get from this code:

```
foreach (int item in Util.PullMax(Util.GenRange(iMin, iMax).Concat(Util.GenRange(iMin + 5, iMax + 5))))
{
    Console.Write($"\nMaximum Value: {item}");
}
```

```
Maximum Value: 15
Maximum Value: 14
Maximum Value: 13
Maximum Value: 12
Maximum Value: 11
Maximum Value: 10
Maximum Value: 10
Maximum Value: 9
Maximum Value: 9
Maximum Value: 8
Maximum Value: 8
Maximum Value: 7
Maximum Value: 6
Maximum Value: 5
Maximum Value: 4
Maximum Value: 3
```

This should be the expected results:

```
Maximum Value: 15
Maximum Value: 14
Maximum Value: 13
Maximum Value: 12
Maximum Value: 11
Maximum Value: 10
Maximum Value: 9
Maximum Value: 8
Maximum Value: 7
Maximum Value: 6
Maximum Value: 5
Maximum Value: 4
Maximum Value: 3
```

I was asked to show Util.GenRange()

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GenRange(int iMin, int iMax)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = iMin; i < iMax; i++)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
                yield break;
            }
        }
```

The result I am getting has duplicates and I cannot have them. How can I get rid of them without any copies or temporary collections or even using distinct?

Comment: ***Why*** can't you use `Distinct` or temporary collections?

Comment: You have an IEnumerable, and you want to remove duplicate. That look like Distinct.. So lets see how district do it [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,836). If there was a solution that cost no ressource it would have been there

Comment: How does `Util.GenRange` look like? If you somehow generating/getting two enumerables with the same max value, how do you expect the method to know to ignore(?) one of them in the output without some way of "remembering" what was already put out? _You'd_ have to guarantee that you will _never_ generate/get more than one enumerable with the same max value. -- btw. that sounds like a rather strange stipulation, bordering on an XY problem...

Comment: But as the set is ordered you don't neet a whole `Set`..

Comment: _I need to find and return the highest values_ - Can you show what is expected result? What you mean by "Highest values", highest of what? What makes value to belong to "highest values"?

Comment: I am not supposed to use Distinct or temporary collections as those are the requirements. Also I have added the expected results.

Comment: How would I got about comparing the values?

Comment: @Corak To be fair, it is a _good_ constraint in the sense that it forces you to implement it in an efficient way.

Comment: What you need to do is create a variable holding the last result you had, so you can compare your current result against it. A lot of this type of requirements needs you to create such a variable to put your last result in. You'll see it in sorting algorithms too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that avoids the multiple enumeration problem with the other solution (i.e. the other solution iterates more than once over the enumerable):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T> (IEnumerable<T> sourcelist) where T : IComparable
{
    IEnumerable<T> list = sourcelist.OrderByDescending(item => item);
 
    T previousValue = default(T);
    bool firstIteration = true;
 
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        if (firstIteration)
            firstIteration = false;
        else if (item.CompareTo(previousValue) == 0)
            continue;
        
        previousValue = item;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Basically it always returns the first element - then for elements other than the first it returns them only if they don't match the previous element. This will be dramatically faster for some classes of data (e.g. where sourcelist is an `IQueryable`) since it avoids the unnecessary counting etc.

Answer (score 1):

Lots and lots of different options for writing this algorithm yourself.

**However it is always better to reuse code where possible, only problem is you haven't found a LINQ method that does a Distinct Sorting in only one pass.**

But there is [**`SortedSet<T>`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_SortedSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__), which is basically a sorted *distinct* list, and it claims `O(n log n)` for insertion, and can take an `IEnumerable`. It does not throw on duplicates, it just ignores them:

```cs
static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return new SortedSet<T>(source, comparer);
}
```

**To get it to go in descending order, flip the compare result in your lambda by using a `-`:**

```cs
list.PullMax((a, b) => -a.CompareTo(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I need to find and return the highest values within my IEnumerable list but cannot show any duplicates.

From your code, I gather that you don't want only the highest value of your input sequence, but that you want the values ordered in descending order, without any duplicates.

To make usage LINQ-like, I'll create it as an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Extension method is merely syntactic sugar. It makes it look for the reader as if the method that you call is a method of the class.

Instead of calling a method in a static class:

```
var customers = FetchCustomers();
var maxCustomers = ExtraCustomerFunctions.PullMax(customers);
```

You can write:

```
var customers = FetchCustomers();
var maxCustomers = customers.PullMax();
```

The only thing you have to do for this, is to create a static method in a static class and use the word `this` before the first parameter.

**Back to your question**

**Requirement**
From the input sequence of objects of class `T`, which implements `IComparable<T>`, return a sequence with as first element the largest item, then the largest but one, etc. Discard Duplicate values.

```
public class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> orderedSource = source.OrderByDescending(item => item);

        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = orderedSource.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // The sequence is not empty.
                // return the first item, and remember that you returned this value
                T lastReturnedItem = enumerator.Current;
                yield return lastReturnedItem;

                // enumerate the rest, skip the items with a value that you just returned
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    // Current is either as large as the last returned one, or it is smaller
                    if (enumerator.Curren.Compare(lastReturnedItem) < 0)
                    {
                        // Current is smaller; return it, and remember that you returned it
                        lastReturnedItem = enumerator.Current;
                        yield return lastReturnedItem;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems a lot of code, but most of it is comment.

Usage:

```
int[] numbers = FetchNumbers();
var pulledMaxNumbers = numbers.PullMax();
```

### There is room for improvement!

If you intend to reuse this method, consider to make it more generic, more LINQ-like. This way it will be easy to use the method for items that are not comparable.

Customers are not comparable, but you can compare them on BirthDay, or PostCode. With only a little change it is possible to PullMax customers:

```
// PullMax customers, oldest Customers first:
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = this.FetchCustomers();
var result = customers.PullMax(customer => customer.BirthDay);
```

To do this, make a method with a property selector and a generic IComparer.
Something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.PullMax(item => item);
}

static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> propertySelector)
{
    return source.PullMax(propertySelector, null);
}

static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    // TODO: check source and keySelector not null
    if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

    // rest of code is similar to code above, difference: check on keySelector
    IEnumerable<T> orderedSource = source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = orderedSource.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            T currentValue = enumerator.Current;
            yield return currentValue
            TKey lastKeyValue = keySelector(currentValue);

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                currentValue = enumerator.Current;
                TKey keyValue = keySelector(currentValue);
                if (comparer.Compare(keyValue, lastKeyValue) < 0)
                {
                     yield return currentValue;
                     lastKeyValue = keyValue;
                }
```

etc.

You can even put your PullMax inside a LINQ concatenation:

```
var result = Customers.Where(customer => customer.City == "New York")
    .PullMax(customer => customer.PostCode)
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Well completely without any temporary variable or distinct there is no chance. BUT the cheapest way to solve is having ONE temporary variable for holding the LAST returned value and check for that value if its the same.

maybe this method should do the trick

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> PullMax<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourcelist) where T : IComparable
        {
            IEnumerable<T> list = sourcelist.OrderByDescending(item => item);
            if (sourcelist.LongCount() > 0) yield return list.ElementAt(0);
            T tmp = sourcelist.ElementAt(0);
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(tmp) < 1) continue;
                tmp = item;
                yield return item;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can use temporary variables but what would I need to do exactly?

Comment: added a possible method. untested

Comment: okay, changed method to catch that null problem. yielding the first item if available and do following checks against new tmp variable

Comment: Its giving me both the start and the end of the list only, so Maximum Value: 15 and Maximum Value: 3

Comment: Yes I changed it. It now shows the correct order however it starts off with Maximum Value: 3 before showing the correct output

Comment: I found out why I was getting the extra Maximum Value: 15. I removed the line:
if (sourcelist.LongCount() > 0) yield return list.ElementAt(0);
Now I am getting the intended results. I believe my problem has been solved. Thank you to both of you @mjwills